# My project is still using graph-i-ql instead of playground

Tags: graphql, gatsby, prisma-graphql, graphiql

How can I use playground instead of graph-i-ql?

[gatsby docs - using graphql playground](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/using-graphql-playground/)

I have tried a couple of ways to load playground instead of graph-i-ql, Updated xcode, used different browsers, globally installed playground, rebooted, etc. My project is still loading graph-i-ql at http://localhost:8000/___graphql after running `gatsby develop` in my fish shell.

[my github repo](https://github.com/jastuccio/gatsby-bootcamp)

```
{
  "name": "gatsby-bootcamp",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Gatsby Bootcamp by Andrew Mead",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "GATSBY_GRAPHQL_IDE=playground gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write src/**/*.{js,jsx}",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.0",
    "gatsby": "^2.3.16",
    "gatsby-cli": "^2.5.9",
    "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "^3.0.7",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "graphql-playground": "^1.3.17",
    "prettier": "^1.17.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I cloned your project & it works. Are you sure you're running `yarn develop` instead of `gatsby develop`? `yarn develop` will run with `GATSBY_GRAPHQL_IDE=playground`, `gatsby develop` will not.

Comment: Now it makes sense! When I run `npm run develop` playground loads.  Thank you @DerekNguyen. Do you want to write an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: Glad it worked for you! No worries, you can post an answer yourself & mark it as correct. To add a bit info: all `npm run develop` or `yarn develop` does, is to run the script you specified in `package.json`. You can also just run `GATSBY_GRAPHQL_IDE=playground gatsby develop` directly in command line, it's the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `npm run develop` instead of `gatsby develop` runs the scripts command from package.json

The way it is written in my scripts `npm run develop` runs `GATSBY_GRAPHQL_IDE=playground` before it runs `gatsby develop` This causes playground to load instead of graph-i-ql.

thank you [Derek Nguyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10340970/derek-nguyen)